# If jupyter notebook is ready but Dask dashboard is still showing that its running some task, can I execute my next cell?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask, python-xarray, dask-distributed

I am new to `Dask`. I was using it with an `xarray` dataset. I persisted the dataset in memory and the `jupyter` cell showed that it was ready (no more asterisk). But the `dask` dashboard was busy executing the task. I didn't understand. When this happens, should I wait till `dask` dashboard has stabilized or am I free to run the next cell?

Answer (score 1):

If the subsequent code doesn't depend on the task being calculated, it's possible to continue running some code.

For example, let's say you submitted calculation of `ddf.map_partitions(some_func)` and persist the dataframe:

```py
ddf = ddf.map_partitions(some_func)
ddf = ddf.persist()
```

Then, if you try to run some `ddf`-specific code, Jupyter will wait until `ddf` (or the relevant chunks/partitions) are computed by the scheduler, e.g. if you try to run `len(ddf)` it will block until the full `ddf` is computed.

If the subsequent code does not require submission to the scheduler, then it will run without waiting for `ddf`. For example, if downstream you want to create a list of some numbers this will run right away:

```py
list_evens = [i for i in range(1000) if i%2==0]
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to wait. Isn't that great?

xarray and dask work together to schedule tasks, and dask's scheduler automatically tracks the [*dependency graph*](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/graphs.html) of all tasks.

If a local xarray operation requires the work to be completed, dask will block execution until all needed operations are complete. For example, plotting will immediately trigger computation and will bring all necessary data to the notebook so it can be rendered. Similarly, calling `compute()` or executing another operation which requires the data to be local or executed, such as writing to a file, plotting, coercing to a native python or numpy data type (e.g. `da.values` or `bool(da.isnull().any())`) will all trigger computation on the workers, and the operation will block until the necessary tasks have completed. Conversely, distributed operations which only return a dask-backed xarray object will only do enough computing locally to *schedule* the operations on the cluster.

[Persist](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-best-practices.html#persist-intelligently) operations are a special case where the task graph is executed on the workers, but the result is not brought to the local notebook, and the notebook may continue executing while the work is done. If you'd like to wait for the work to complete, you can always block progress with [`dd.wait()`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/futures.html#waiting-on-futures). But you don't necessarily need to - if you execute a later step which *does* need the data, this step will block until the computations are complete.

See the docs on [using xarray with dask](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/dask.html#using-dask-with-xarray), [Dask's Lazy Execution tutorial](https://tutorial.dask.org/01x_lazy.html), and [Dask: Best Practices](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-best-practices.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Persist submits the task graph to the scheduler and returns future objects pointing to your results. So the calculation will be running in the background while you continue your work. You don't need to wait for the dashboard to finish.

Comment: clarifying that xarray will *schedule* the operations immediately. The computations on the remote workers will wait until their dependencies are completed to begin, but nothing triggers a `compute()` on the client jupyter notebook side, so the entire graph does not need to complete. For example, if your task graph depends on reading 20 files, and then you execute a cell multiplying all results by 2, dask will begin executing these next tasks as soon as any workers become available with completed results from the initial operation, not until the whole graph is done.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you for the clarification, I will delete that part from my answer. I think in my case I was also using datashader which needs to access the whole dataset but that's a different story.

Comment: Yep, although datashader similarly works with xarray to identify the data it needs and only triggers computation on those portions of the array. So if your array is indexed by lat, lon, with chunks in lat and lon, and you design a canvas with x_range and y_range covering a small subset of the domain, only the needed part of the data will be computed.

Comment: yes except for the aggregation stage, it needs to access the whole dataset.

Comment: if the canvas only covers part of the x, y domain, the aggregation step only needs access to that part of the domain. depending on how your data is partitioned, you may not need to compute the whole graph even for aggregation & rendering. the same is true for plotting.

Comment: ok! in my case the canvas does cover the whole domain. Thank you for the heads up though.

Comment: totally undersand - the only reason I was being persistent is because this is an *answer* so I was clarifying for the benefit of the OP and others who come along too ;)

Comment: oh absolutely! And I appreciate that you do that :)